# What's the easiest way to convert a big but simple DB from SQLite to SQL Server and back?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I've got a database that is very simple (just a couple of simple tables) but pretty big (about a GiB in SQLite). When developing it I've done my best to use only very standard column types: `INT, DOUBLE, CHAR, VARCHAR` (but these are SQL Server's `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` to be used in place of SQLite's UTF-8 `CHAR` and `VARCHAR`) and no DBMS-specific functionality.

What's the easiest way to convert the database from SQLite to SQL Server and back?

I don't mind to define the target database by hand instead of having all the DDL generated from the source but I seek to automate the data migration.

**UPDATE:**

The easiest way I've found myself is to export from SQLite with

```
> sqlite3 mydb.sqlite
sqlite> .headers off
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output mytable.csv
sqlite> select * from `mytable`;
```

then remove quotes

```
tr -d \" < mytable.csv > mytable-plain.csv
```

convert from Unix (LF line endings) to DOS (CR+LF line endings) text format (as `tr` is a Unix tool and outputs Unix)

```
unix2dos mytable-plain.csv
```

and import it into the SQL Server with `BULK INSERT`

```
BULK
INSERT [dbo].[mytable]
FROM 'c:\mytable-plain.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

assuming that the identical empty table is already created in the SQL Server schema.

`cygwin` is needed to run `tr` and `unix2dos` on Windows.

It took me half an hour (on my Core 2 Duo laptop) to import a half-GiB CSV file into SQL Server.

I still believe there is an easier way. Perhaps there is a T-SQL function to query a different data source through ODBC or a program that selects from the source database and inserts into the target (I can hardly believe nobody has yet written such).

Comment: never tried it but I'd look at something like an SSIS package

Comment: This came into my mind to but sounds a little bit overkill for me. The task seems very simple. It would be faster to code it than to learn SSIS I think. I am just curious if there is no such a handy tool already.

Comment: You may be looking for [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and/or the [rowset functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187957.aspx) that allow you to query an OLE DB source from within SQL Server. I know nothing about SQLite, so I don't know if this is a good solution in your case; linked servers can be awkward to work with.